# Statistics how many times you have opened for every Apps (Intents) in Android

Tags: android, root, appstats

Just like App Stat for iOS in Cydia.
http://www.mytechutopia.net/2011/04/appstat/

how can i do such statistics? 
User may use different Launchers
so i think i need some way to "hook" other apps' Intent on create
I am afraid that won't be supported by Android SDK

however, if we have *root*ed devices, shall we got any chance?
any ideas are welcome.